# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, model, laravel-5.8

Good, I have a database already created; and when making the model I specify the primary key with 
`$primaryKey = "idturnos";` but when searching with Turn enter code here:: where `('idturnos', $ id) -> first ();` 
I get the following message

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'

```
class Turno extends Model
{
    //
    public $table = 'turnos';
    protected $PrimaryKey = "idturnos";
    public $timestamps = false;

}

Controller:
        $actualizar = App\Turno::where('idturnos', $id)->first();
        $actualizar->nomb_turno = strtoupper($request->nomb_turno);
        $actualizar->descri_turno = strtoupper($request->descri_turno);
enter code here        $actualizar->save();

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `turnos` set `nomb_turno` = LOLA, `descri_turno` = XDA where `id` is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

you know need to use where clause

try these

```php
    $actualizar = App\Turno::find(1);
    $actualizar->nomb_turno = strtoupper($request->nomb_turno);
    $actualizar->descri_turno = strtoupper($request->descri_turno);
    $actualizar->update();
    dd($actualizar);
```

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'turnos.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `turnos` where `turnos`.`id` = 2 limit 1)

Comment: what happens is that it does not consider me the name of the custom id, but if it saves again just edit it gives me that error.

Comment: Instead of where method use find a method so the instance will find the primary key from model variable

Comment: I will see how to solve it, thanks for the answer. :)